# Finding Values "t" for Distance

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

The question is as follows:

> The position of a starship is given by the equation $P_t = (18 + 3t, 24 + 4t, 110 - 5t)$. For what values of $t$ is the starship within 100 units of a space station placed at $(10, 20, 30)$?

I set up the distance formula as: 
$$\sqrt{((18 - 3t - 10)^2 + (24 + 4t - 20)^2 + (110-5t-30)^2))} \space \space \le 100$$

When I simplify I get the following quadratic equation:

$$6480 - 840t + 66t^2 \le 10,000$$

However, the roots do not equal to the answer of: $-3.856 < t < 18.256$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your square root you have $18-3t-10$. It should be $18+3t-10$. With that correction, the answer should match.

Comment: looks too close to a  geometric mean to me in which case maybe cube root instead of sqrt and maybe cube the co-ordinates ( just a guess).

Comment: @geo_freak: You made more than one algebraic error. So after you correct $18-3t-10$ to $18+3t-10$, expand more carefully. Of course, you should simplify _inside_ the parentheses before expanding. For example, $18 + 3t-10$ simplifies to $8+3t$.

Comment: $(8+3t)(8+3t) = 64 + 48t + 9t^2$ Is that right?

Comment: Yes, of course. If you suspect you simplified an expression incorrectly, try plugging in a value as a spot check. For example, for the product you expanded in your previous comment, plug in $t=-3$ on both sides. Or $t=1$. Or some other small number.

Comment: I found my error and was able to solve it! Thank you so much for catching my mistake :)

Comment: No problem.${}{}{}$